# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: ruby

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

#Function for Reading the Webpages

def open(url)
  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
end


available_data_file=File.open('C:/Users/modi/Desktop/DataFile.txt', 'r+')
available_data_file.each do |definition|
  link=definition.split(/";"/)
  link.each do |address|
    spyware_url=address[3]
    spyware_data=open("#{spyware_url}")
    puts spyware_data
  end
end
```

I am getting the error as follows::

c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in `initialize': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in`open'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in `connect'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:48:in`timeout'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in`connect'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:557:in `do_start'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:546:in`start'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in `get_response'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:356:in`get'
    from 1983.rb:7:in `open'
    from 1983.rb:132
    from 1983.rb:130:in`each'
    from 1983.rb:130
    from 1983.rb:128:in

Comment: Are you able to open `spyware_url ` directly in browser?

Comment: I am giving the url  https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=49893
but it is redirecting to the following url:



https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/49893-removal-instructions-for-a-fast-antivirus/